# Extract lines from character to character in a loop

Tags: sed, scripting, special-characters

I have this line here and it works great to extract lines from a character to a second character (excluding the last line):

```
sed -n -e '/>AB123|x2/,/>/ p' filename | sed -e '$d' > output
```

But when I write it as a script to process more than one, it does not work any more. I tried all combinations of "'> with "$C" in the loop and command, but does not work. Could you have a look at it please?

```
for C in >AB123|x2
do
sed -n -e '/"$C"/,/>/ p' filename | sed -e '$d' >> output
done
```

Comment: you are overwriting the file `output` each time you run this line. If you want to append the values, you must use `>>`

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for that. The loop has the >> to add to the output file. But there is no output from the loop. It writes an empty file. It seems like the loop characters wont get recognised in the sed command.

Syntax error: redirection unexpected, with:
**for C in >AB123|x2**

Empty output file with:
**for C in '>AB123|x2'**

Comment: Ah, I misread it then (or jumped to conclusions).  Yes, you'll need to quote the characters since they contain both redirection and a pipe. What is the expected output you'd like to receive?

Comment: FYI you have the $C variable inside of single quotes, meaning that it will not expand to the variable and instead you get a literal '$C'.

Comment: And what are the contents of 'filename'.

Comment: Thanks Charles! that worked. See below.. All in '', character and variable. Thanks for the easy fix..

Answer (score 0):

that worked! Thanks for your input! Characters in the loop with '' AND variable in command with ''. High five and many thanks! P

```
for C in '>AB123|x2'
  do
  sed -n -e '/'"$C"'/,/>/p' filename | sed -e '$d' >> output
done
```

(assuming there's only one occurrence of the section in the input).